# Merge dataframes on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There are two tables like:  `first_name`, `last_name`, `date of birth`, ...

I would like to create a new table with only the people listed that are present in both tables.

If I try to lookup by looping an "isin"-Method, I can look for a match for one column, but I would like to match both columns at the same time.

Comment: Use merge, with how = 'inner'..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending the answer mentioned in the comment (by @Scott Boston), if you have the following dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['Jack', 'Brown', '1980-01-01'], ['Joe', 'Doe', '1990-02-02']
                            , ['John', 'Jones', '2000-03-03']])
                   , columns=['first_name', 'last_name', 'birth_date'])
```

df1 would be:

```
first_name last_name birth_date
Jack       Brown     1980-01-01
Joe        Doe       1990-02-02
John       Jones     2000-03-03
```

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['Jack', 'Brown', '2020-01-29'], ['Joe', 'Smith', '1999-09-09']
                            , ['Sarah', 'Morphy', '2011-11-11']])
                   , columns=['first_name', 'last_name', 'birth_date'])
```

df2 would be:

```
first_name last_name birth_date
Jack       Brown     2010-10-10
Joe        Smith     1999-09-09
Sarah      Morphy    2011-11-11
```

```
result = pd.merge(df1, df2, how="inner", on=["first_name", "last_name"])
```

Your result would be this:

```
first_name last_name birth_date_x birth_date_y
Jack       Brown     1980-01-01   2010-10-10
```

You can change `_x` and `_y` suffixes as well by adding `suffixes=["_df1", "_df2"]`

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time by giving me such a comprehensive answer - I really apprechiate that